# Cannot make requests on external URLs outside my localhost

Tags: node.js, header

I get this error when making a GET over 'https://www.google.com/'.

Failed to load https://www.google.com/: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.

On server side I use cors:

```
server.use(cors({
origin: '*',
credentials: true
}));

server.use(function(req, res, next) {
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, 
Content-Type, Accept");
next();
});

server.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
next();
});
```

On client side I have a cookieService:

```
getCookies(URL) {
const headers = new Headers();
**headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');**
return this.http.get(URL, { headers: headers }).map(res => res.json());
}
```

On an angular component I call this function:

```
searchCookies() {
this.cookieService.getCookies('https://www.google.com').subscribe();
}
```

Is there a way to add this header to the GET response? Or is there another way to acces to an external URL like https://www.google.com?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CORS headers, which you are adding to **`localhost`** via your server response, do not work for google - the whole idea of CORS is that the 3rd party server (in this case https://google.com) can defend itself from Cross Origin Resource Sharing.

TL;DR - https://google.com doesn't allow `localhost` to access the website. If you want to scrape the website - you'd have to access it from node.js itself, rather than client-side JS.

Comment: Thanks Justas. Yes I've tried from the server side and now I can make a get over https://google.com like this: router.get('/cookies', (req, res) => {
    request('https://google.com', function (err, response, body) {
        ...
        }
    });